# How would a jasmine standard directory tree look like?

Tags: jasmine

I was reading a tutorial about Jasmine testing and it suggested you should use the standard Jasmine directory tree structure (which seems to be related with RSpec directory tree structure). I have googled for an hour and can't find any info about this standard directory tree.

How would a standard Jasmine testing environment directory tree look like, considering a very complete scenario (with HTML fixtures, JSON fixtures, specs, etc)?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't think there is any actual standard. As far as I know the structure they provide is just a suggested structure and it's never enforced in any way. Just go with a directory tree that will make it easy for you and other developer to find and organize the files.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that there is no standard, but there seems to be some suggested ways of organising your project directory tree structure.

After working these last week on some ruby and jasmine projects it seems to me that the suggested structure is:

```
test
    SpecRunner.html

    jasmine
        lib
            <jasmine.js and other files>

    spec
        javascripts
            my-spec.js

            fixtures
                my-fixture.html

            helpers
                my-helper.js

            support
                yasmine.yml
                yasmine_helper.rb
```

Any feedback will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not an actual standard , but i can tell you the way i am doing

```
Scripts

     app
        test.js

     spec
        test-spec.js

     testrunner
        SpecRunner.html
```

or you can do as you like . Its totally up to you .